# Creating a function that takes a list of words, and return a set of words in the sentence

Tags: python, string, list, set

1. need to create a function that takes a string

e.g. "hello it is a nice day today and it is hot"

2. the function needs to use the LIST of words in the string, and create a SET consisting of the words in the string.

the output should be : ("hello" "it" "is" "a" "nice" "day" "today" "and" "hot")
NOTE: the set only has unique words from the sentence, no repeating words

I tried it myself but it says its wrong:

```
opening_line="It was the best of times, it was the worst of times"

def get_vocabulary(word_list):

  words = word_list.split()

  dickens_words = set()
  dickens_words.add(words)

  return words

print(get_vocabulary(opening_line))
```

Comment: What if you use `append` instead of `add`?

Comment: Use `update` instead of `add` and return `dickens_words`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the entire list as a single element to the set. Instead, you could construct a set from list, which would add all the words individually to the set:

```py
def get_vocabulary(word_list):
    return set(word_list.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is add() accept only one element.

Try adding the link when you create the set

dickens_words = set(words)

Answer (score 0):

A = list(input("statement:").strip().split(' '))

print (' '.join(list(dict.fromkeys(A))))

Comment: Hi Meysam, welcome to SO. Please use code formatting and provide some context for your answer, it is generally discouraged just to post code alone.